# Authenticating user for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, authorization

Referring to the docs got [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box),

```
// Check permissions
if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
        return;
    } else {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;
    }
}
```

If I want to authenticate a user for editing a custom post type "portfolio", do I do something like

```
if ($_POST['post_type'] != 'portfolio' || !current_user_can_for_blog($post_id, 'edit_post')) 
    return;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the function [`current_user_can_for_blog`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can_for_blog) expects a blog ID to be passed to it, not a post ID. I would change it to be like this:

```
if( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && $_POST['post_type'] != 'portfolio' ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( $post_id, 'edit_post' ) ) 
        return;
}
```